# Authorization header in ServiceAuthorizationManager is null in second call

Tags: rest, wcf, basic-authentication

I have a WCF REST service which accepts xml data as input and returns some data too. To implement Basic Authentication i use ServiceAuthorizationManager. The CheckAccessCore method calls twice automatically. In first call authorization header in CheckAccessCore is correct, but in second call authorization header is null.

**ServiceAuthorizationManager CheckAccessCore method**

```
protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        var authHeader = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers["Authorization"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authHeader))
        {
            var credentials = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authHeader.Substring(6))).Split(':');
            var user = new
            {
                Name = credentials[0],
                Password = credentials[1]
            };

            if (user.Name == "test" && user.Password == "pass")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm =\"CreditData\"");
            throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
    }
```

**WCF Web.config**

```html
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RestBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Xml"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="CreditDataService.Authorization.CreditDataAuthorizationManager, CreditDataService" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="CreditDataService.Services.CreditData" behaviorConfiguration="">
        <endpoint name="REST" behaviorConfiguration="RestBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="CreditDataService.Contracts.ICreditData"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Client**

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:33016/Services/CreditData.svc");
            byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<Request><Firstname>John</Firstname><Lastname>Doe</Lastname><Pid>123456789</Pid></Request>");
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            request.Method = "POST";

            string credentials = "test:pass";
            string enc = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credentials));
            string auth = string.Format("{0} {1}", "Basic", enc);

            request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = auth;

            Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            reqStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            reqStream.Close();

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream respStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                string respStr = new StreamReader(respStream).ReadToEnd();
                MessageBox.Show(respStr);
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Response != null)
            {
                var resp = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                MessageBox.Show(resp);
            }

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Without ServiceAuthorizationManager it works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was webservice's method's UriTemplate. It was empty and when i was calling service there was happening redirecting to the same url only with slash. e.g. when i sent request to "http://localhost/myservice.svc" it was redirected to "http://localhost/myservice.svc/". This arose second request and exactly this second request had Authorization header null. When i added UriTemplate problem solved.